# Android UIAutomatorViewer source code

Tags: android, testing, android-uiautomator

I have been googling for a while looking for UIAutomatorViewer source code, but failed to find it. Can anyone please provide a link to Android UIAutomatorViewer sources.
I need the sources as I am planning to experiment with UIAutomatorViewer.

Comment: [GoogleSource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/swt/+/master/uiautomatorviewer) and [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/com/android/uiautomator/) both have it. Not sure what you've been searching for, because these were in my top 3 hits.

Comment: well I was looking for a specific jar UIAutomatorViewer to be there and didn't see it :( .Thanks a lot, found what I was looking for.

Comment: @Dnavir, prebuilts might be found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/devtools/ (as per the location suggested in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/refs/heads/main/README.txt)

Answer (score 1):

It's here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/aecdc4a/uiautomator/utils/uiautomatorviewer/src/com/android/uiautomator but it doesn't fit line numbers of my stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

uiautomatorviewer is now located in "tools/swt.git". Thus the location would be: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/swt/+/refs/heads/main

This [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/5413b20f8ce9e3bf934c8d2b04b4f93b583c20d3) shows that it was moved to "sdk"

```plaintext
removing uiautomatorviewer from frameworks/testing

It is to be moved into sdk
```

This [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/refs/heads/main/README.txt) of "sdk" says

```plaintext
Some of the SDK tools sources have moved out of the sdk.git project.
They are no longer found here.

Instead they can be found in the tools/base.git and the tools/swt.git projects.
If you need to view/change the source and lack these folders, you can bring
them by using a repo init command such as:

$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -g all,-notdefault,tools
$ repo sync [-j N]

The libraries that are sourced in tools/base and tools/swt are converted to
prebuilts which are located in prebuilts/devtools. These prebuilts are the
ones being used when doing a "make sdk".
```